# Phonegap 1.0 on sound complete dispaly (audio file nil)

Tags: javascript, iphone, android, html, cordova

I am using phonegap 1.0 The audio file play well but when the audio is complete, it generate (audio file nil).
This was not happening in phonegap 0.9.

What may be the solution for this.

Comment: If I use old version of phonegap ,then email plugin may not work. Any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has been fixed in PhoneGap 1.1.0

It sounds like an example of issue #208

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-android/issues/208